# Nested loop AttributeError: __exit__ (Selenium script) when opening file

Tags: python, selenium, nested-loops

I am trying to do a loop within a loop to pass a variable in the message box of send_keys. I seem to have an error when I open the second file "test2.txt" which has the the information I want to pass to the variable. I'm pretty new to python and I'm not entirely sure what it means and haven't been able to resolve it by searching.

Any help on getting this to work would be much appreciated.

**Code snippet:**

```
 with open('test2.txt').read() as lp:
                    current = 1
                    for line in lp:
                        field_box.send_keys("""ID:""", lp)
                        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-buttons').submit()
                        time.sleep(2)
```

**Full code:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def doAction():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome ('/Users/xxx/chromedriver') # Set correct path for chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
    driver.get('https://www.site.com.au/login'); # Set which region you're working with
    time.sleep(1)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    search_box.send_keys('xxx') # Set your e-mail/username
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    search_box.send_keys('xxx') # Set your password
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-primary.btn-md.btn-cm.pull-right').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('test.txt') as fp:
        print '============================================'
        print 'Starting to disable entities................'
        print '============================================'
        current = 1
        for line in fp:
            url = 'https://www.site.com.au/admin/entities/%s' % line
            driver.get(url);
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='false']").click()
            field_box_clear = driver.find_element_by_name('disabledReason').clear()
            field_box = driver.find_element_by_name('disabledReason')
            with open('test2.txt').read() as lp:
                current = 1
                for line in lp:
                    field_box.send_keys("""ID:""", lp)
                    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-buttons').submit()
                    time.sleep(2)

            print "Doing",current,"Of",file_len('test.txt')
            current += 1
            print '- Disabled entity: %s' % line
        print '============================================'
        print 'Completed disabling entities................'
        print '============================================'

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doAction()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to wrap `open('test2.txt').read()` with `with` [statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/).

> To implement a context manager, we define a class containing an
>   **enter** and **exit** method.

The result of `open('test2.txt').read()` does not implement that. Instead of, you should wrap `open('test2.txt')` (to automatically close the file).

```
with open('test2.txt') as lp:
    current = 1
    ...
```